# How do Objective-C comparison blocks know their arguments for the sortUsingComparator method?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm in the process of learning Objective-C, and am trying to get my head wrapped around the idea of using blocks.

In an example I'm seeing, there is a method meant to sort an NSArray named book in alphabetical order by name:

```
-(void) sort
{
    [book sortUsingComparator:
        ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
            return [[obj1 name] compare: [obj2 name]];
    } ];
}
```

How does the method pass the objects to the obj1 and obj2 parameters? Does the sortUsingComparator somehow automatically pass 2 objects to its comparator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortUsingComparator:` iterates over the array and calls the block with various pairs of objects to determine how to sort them. There's no magic here — it's a normal sorting function, but it uses your block instead of `>` to compare the values.

Comment: To make it a little more clear, @Henry's example compares based on the object's names. However, you could define the block to compare based on their creation dates, ages, preferred beers, or whatever other properties exist on the objects being passed in. That's the beauty of blocks. They are self-contained blocks of code that can be passed around and defined as needed!

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on the implementation of the sort, every time the sort algorithm needs to compare 2 elements this will get called. You don't really need to know what will get passed to it, just define an order relationship for the types that get passed. It'll ask what he needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

Some extra information about blocks that answers your question, a block can be assigned to a variable and called like a function. The sortUsingComparator: method signature is:

```
- (void)sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

cmptr is the variable that holds your block. The sortUsingComparator: method will run every element in the array through its sort algorithm and, as Fernando pointed out, every time the sort algorithm needs to compare 2 elements it's called like this:

```
NSComparisonResult result = cmptr(obj1, obj2);
```

And your block code is executed. So the answer to your question:

> Does the sortUsingComparator somehow automatically pass 2 objects to its comparator?

is yes :)

Answer (score 0):

The sort method does something like this (I'm not claiming the `sort:` method does this exactly, but the idea remains):

```
for (i = 0; i < [book count]; i++) {
    id currentObject = [book objectAtIndex:i];      // obj1
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        id sortedObject = [book objectAtIndex:j];   // obj2
        NSComparisonResult result = sortBlock(currentObject, sortedObject);
        // Insert currentObject where appropriate; perform the rest of the sort
    }
}
```

In this case, I'm assuming that the block's parameter name is `^sortBlock` (the caret denotes a block). You invoke blocks just like regular functions, with parentheses and arguments.

So to answer your question…it's automatic in the sense that *you* don't have to think about it, but there's no magic going on. 
Hope this helps!